# How to suppress the Ding sound when Application.DoEvents() is used

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

When using the KeyDown event on a TextBox, is there a way to suppress the Ding if we want to use the command Application.DoEvents()? I use this command to refresh the screen (otherwise there won't be any visible changes until the function DoSomething() completes.

```
    void TbTextKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return) {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;  
            Application.DoEvents(); // this command triggers the Ding
            DoSomething(); // this function may take a few seconds to complete
        }
    }
```

Comment: Windows Config Panel / Sounds / System ?

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer not to interfere with the system sounds, if possible.

Comment: `async void TbTextKeyDown` and `await Task.Run(() => DoSomething())` without `DoEvents()`

Comment: I am not sure i get your question proper. If you have your ding in your Do evernts, and wana ignore when textkeydown event why dont you send with Bool to active or deactive the ding.

Comment: e.SuppressKeyPress just can't work when you do this, DoEvents gets the KeyPress event fired before the key can be suppressed.  Just yet another of the many re-entrancy problems caused by DoEvents.  Don't do it.  You didn't leave enough breadcrumbs to guess exactly what needs to be updated, start with this.Update().

Comment: Hello Hans, thanks for clarification. What I want is to clear some elements of the form (text boxes) as soon as I press Return. The function DoSomething() takes a few seconds to complete, then it fills the same text boxes with new data.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for the suggestion. It works ok. You can add it as an answer and I will choose it.

Comment: Hans, I tried the function Update() instead of Application.DoEvents() and it does the job. I was not aware of this function :)

Comment: Also, you just need `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`. This property also sets `e.Handled = true;` internally. You shouldn't run methods that take that much time to complete in a `KeyDown` event. You should mention what task this code is supposed to perform. A sync method will prevent a user to type, an async one will cause trouble, you need to handle the cacellation ot the previous one before starting another, eventually etc.